# How to query insert on updated rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Hey i'm trying to update a table and create an insert a row to another table.

I have this update query :

```
UPDATE logs_month SET status ='1'
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(month,"%m/%y") = '11/12'
```

And i want it to be something like this:

```
UPDATE logs_month SET status ='1',
(INSERT INTO some_table (columns) values (values from the updated row))
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(month,"%m/%y") = '11/12'
```

How can this be done?

I don't want to use 2 queries because this update can accour several times a month and i want to insert only the rows currently updates to prevent duplicates without using unique indexes.

Comment: side note: why are you doing such transformation with the date? that will incur extra work for the db. Query the data in the way it's store and then transform it in _reder time_

Comment: Well that will require code to transform it, is date_format really that cost affective then preforming a concatenation and replacing "/"s to "-"?

Comment: If you apply a function to a column, the query won't use the indexes since the db need to know the result of the function call for _every_ row to see what matches the _where_ condition. That make the function call really expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE logs_month SET status ='1'
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(month,"%m/%y") = '11/12';
COMMIT;
INSERT INTO some_table (columns) values (select columns
from logs_month where DATE_FORMAT(month,"%m/%y") = '11/12';
```

You can do with **TRIGGER** also,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `logs_m` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `logs_month`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.status=1 THEN
    INSERT INTO some_table (field) values (NEW.field);
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

You can do like this

Comment: Well that's just running another query, is there someway to make it  sub-query style?

Comment: Actually In oracle we can write triggers to do this. Do you have triggers like any concept in mysql??

Comment: Ya triggers exist in mysql, never used it though, could u explain how can that be done using triggers? because i know you can set before/after not during...

Comment: Also,your code above will just insert all of the results from this month, I need to seperate those times so an update can occour several times in a month and this would just duplicate rows.

Comment: yeah for this purpose trigger will do. This will update only new entries.. see my updated answer.

Comment: This causes syntax error... u sure about the syntax or is it oracle syntax?

Comment: what have you run? Did you give the column names properly. Post what have u run..

Comment: The delimeter caused the syntax error, i've fixed your code please approove it. and this did work thank you very much!

Comment: yeah I forgot to add that man. You are welcome. Pls accept the answer. Happy new year :)